# Python: Reccurence for the digitsum sequence

Tags: python, sequence

I'm a coding beginner, so please excuse my trivial code errors. I'm trying to write a program in Python that picks up the sequence [A004207](https://oeis.org/A004207) aka. "Sum of digits of all previous terms".

```
 a_n = 1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 23, 28, 38, 49, ... (with a_0=1)
```

This is part of [Euler problem #551](https://projecteuler.net/problem=551).
But i'm far from solving that one, I've been focusing on getting the brute-force reccurence code right and now I'm stuck.

Below are my efforts this far, but it's not working. The `SumOfDigits` function is ok, but the `DigitSum(n)` is a mess.

Someone have any ideas?

---

> Sum of digits for a given number x

```
def SumOfDigits(x):
  sum = 0
  while (x != 0):
      sum = sum + x % 10
      x = x // 10

  return sum
```

> Sum of all digits in sequence up to n

```
def DigitSum(n):

  i = 1
  step = 1        # Step in sequence
  result = 1      # initialize result
  number = 10     # Endterm in sequence

  step = min(step, n-i)
  for j in range(0,step):
      if j < step:
          j = j + 1
          i = i + 1

  result = result + SumOfDigits(result)

  if i > n:
      return result

print(DigitSum(number),"Sum is =",result)
```

Answer (score 3):

Notice that

> a(n) = a(n-1) + SumOfDigits(a(n-1))

since a(n-1) is the sum of the digit sums of all the terms prior to a(n-1).  So we can just write

```
 def DigitSum(n):
      a = 1
      for i in range(n):
           a = a + SumOfDigits(a)
      return a
```

Testing it out,

```
>>> [a(i) for i in range(10)]
[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 23, 28, 38, 49, 62]
```

Adjust for whatever indexing you want.

Answer (score 0):

A recursive (but very inefficient) version, with list comprehensions.

```
def SumOfDigits(x):
    sumx = 0
    while (x != 0):
        sumx = sumx + x % 10
        x   = x // 10
    return sumx

def DigitSum(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return sum([SumOfDigits(DigitSum(i)) for i in range(0,n)])

test_set = (1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 23, 28, 38, 49, 62, 70, 77, 91, 101)
result_set = [DigitSum(i) for i in range(0,len(test_set))]
print(result_set)

# [1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 23, 28, 38, 49, 62, 70, 77, 91, 101]
```